# What does update panel do?

Tags: asp.net

I am quite new to asp.net and i want to know what exactly does update panel do.
I've looked into several answers regarding the question, but i can't seem to understand.
Can someone explain it to me in more simplistic manner?

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Rico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update panel is used to execute ASP.NET Ajax calls.
Read more about it [here](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/)